# In Angular2/4/5, How to Securely call WebAPI action, based on Token based Authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I need to know, How to securely call WebAPI action method, after getting token in Angular FrontEnd. Below is my login component code, where after sending username and password, I'm setting usertoken to localstorage. Then I'm navigating to home page. All code used here is based on [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8BlURn6SFk). slight modification is also there, since I'm using Ionic code also in HTML

**login.ts**

```
constructor(private userService : UserService, public navCtrl: NavController) { } 
OnSubmit(userName,password){
         this.userService.userAuthentication(userName,password).subscribe((data : any)=>{
          localStorage.setItem('userToken',data.access_token);
          //this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          this.navCtrl.push(HomeComponent);
        },
        (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
          this.isLoginError = true;
        });
      }
```

In the below code shown, I'm getting userdetails based on given username and password above.Please focus on **OnSubmit()** method of below component. **This is method/event for submitting another form of Home component based on usertoken for which I need your help**

**home.ts**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private userService: UserService) { }    
ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.userService.getUserClaims().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.userClaims = data;    
    });        
  }
OnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
this.userService.UserForm(form.value)
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    localStorage.getItem('userToken');

    if (data.Succeeded == true) {
     // this.resetForm(form);
     return "hello";
    }

  });      
}
```

Please focus on **UserForm** method of below service for which I need your help.

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UIHelperClass } from '../UIHelperClasses/UIHelperClass';
import { Person } from './person.model'; 

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
UserForm(person:Person){
    const body: Person = {
      FirstName: person.FirstName,
      LastName: person.LastName
    }
       //var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'No-Auth':'True'});
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'No-Auth':'False'});
       //return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/api/User/Register', body,{headers : reqHeader});
    return this.http.post(this.uihelper.CallWebAPIUrl("/api/User/AddUser"), body,{headers : reqHeader});        
  }

  userAuthentication(userName, password) {
    var data = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&grant_type=password";
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });
        //return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/token', data, { headers: reqHeader });
    return this.http.post(this.uihelper.CallWebAPIUrl("/token"), data, { headers: reqHeader });           
  }

  getUserClaims(){
       //return  this.http.get(this.rootUrl+'/api/GetUserClaims');
   return  this.http.get(this.uihelper.CallWebAPIUrl("/api/GetUserClaims"));

  }
}
```

How to use, below type of code in above UserForm method of service. I need to secure my request/WebAPI(Based on this token, I need to Call Web API. It may be *Get* or *Post* request). I have referred EmpService.js of [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1223/secure-aspnet-web-api-using-tokens-owin-angularjs) for below code

*user.service.ts*

```
xxx=localStorage.getItem('userToken');
  authHeaders: any[] = [];
  if (xxx) {
    this.authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + xxx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) ,it works perfectly in angular 5 and httpClient, the token will be added automatically to all Http requests after giving the source of your token (localStorage or redux store):

```
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
  HttpClientModule,
  JwtModule.forRoot({
   config: {
     tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
     whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:3001'] // token will be sent to these domains only 
   }
 })
 ]
})
```

you can add an http interceptor to delete token in case of login calls for example